# Change the default swagger path in R

Tags: r, swagger, plumber

I am using plumber function available in R for swagger implementation and getting the default path as http://127.0.0.1:8000/__docs__/. I want to change it to a custom path which looks like http://127.0.0.1:8000/r-api/__docs__/ . How can i do this is in R

I used the plumber function. I tried to set path with "plumber::options_plumber(apiPath  = "r-api")" but got an error what else can be done.